# how to php export to pdf one big query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, export

I have a query with more than 30,000 seats shown correctly in php but I can not export it to pdf. The server does not support the memory size, I increased the maximum memory limit but it continues to fail.

`Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes ...`

I can do so as not to saturate the server maximum memory and export the pdf? Is possible to perform each separate PDF page and then send a single file (PDF with all)?

Any option to run the pdf with the data it me

### SOLUTION!

I´ve solved with this simple solution http://phptopdf.com
This solution is to make an intermediate step => executes the query in php and then displays a button that runs the php to pdf conversion with previously saved query in tmp file.

Comment: How are you generating the PDF...?

Comment: increase memory_limit in php.ini

Comment: i've tried `TCPDF`, `DOMPDF` and `Zend_PDF`. `Zend` seems to be the fastest (i.e. 2.5s instead of 10). I strongly recommend it.

Comment: you only have 8MB of memory? That's too low even for lightweight operations

Comment: If you are doing these types of operations you need more memory. Time for an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following solution and it works well!

Inside your wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\config.inc.php file below the line 24 added the following code:

```
$cfg['MemoryLimit']  = '128M';
And It works well;
```

After inserting Line 19-25 in my config.inc.php file:

```
/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['MemoryLimit'] = '128M';
```

This code worked for me when I face similar issue in past.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you could do, if your hosting allows it, is to set the PHP memory_limit higher by creating your custom php.ini and setting `memory_limit = 64M`. You can check if the setting is working via `phpinfo()`, just remember to delete the line/file you used to check phpinfo to avoid exposing the PHP settings to everyone.

If this is not working, you can try fine-tuning some performance settings.

For TCPDF these are listed under [TCPDF Performance Docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php) and I suggest you apply all the settings and use the practices that may reduce memory consumption and don't affect your output.
For example:

> - If you are not using the Thai language, edit the config/tcpdf_config.php file and set the K_THAI_TOPCHARS constant to false;
> - If you do not need extended chars, edit the config/tcpdf_config.php file and set the default fonts to core fonts;
> - By default TCPDF enables font subsetting to reduce the size of embedded Unicode TTF fonts, this process, that is very slow and requires a lot of memory, can be turned off using setFontSubsetting(false) method;
> - Use core fonts instead of embedded fonts whenever possible;
> - Avoid using the HTML syntax (writeHTML and writeHTMLCell methods) if not strictly required;
> - Split large HTML blocks in smaller pieces;
> - Avoid using transactions if not strictly required;

You could also export page by page and then merge the generated PDF files locally.

Your last option is to either kindly ask your hosting provider to increase PHP memory_limit (at least temporary), or to upgrade to a better hosting plan.

Comment: I tested with hosting php.ini (memory_limit = 64M) but will not let me. currently export to excel, word or html shows no faults with large query, but the problem is only with PDF